# How to get information about domain .NET C++

Tags: c++, .net, dns

I am trying to create an application (Language C++ using .NET 2.0) which allows users to get information about a domain, for example if the domain is **free** or it is **used**, **update date**, **creation date**, **expiration date** etc.

I know about some services which do that like [whois.domaintools](http://whois.domaintools.com/), [whois](http://www.whois.net/)  etc. Now I want to know how they work and how I can write an application which will collect the same information without using any service. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please remove all greetings from your questions. Also, please improve your English.

Comment: Why to remove all greetings ? And why -1 ? Can anybody explain ?

Comment: Read this for example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts (don't know about the -1, but your question is a bit strange. How do you expect to be able to collect DNS information without using some DNS tools/services?)

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan: Search meta.stackoverflow.com for why. Reading the greeting takes our valuable time and we want to help you, but we have little time to do so. Greeting only wastes the time spent on helping you. I didn't downvote you, but you haven't shown us any research you've done or any code that you are having problems with. There is no question here.

Comment: Did you try a websearch for the terms whois and C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these urls:

1. http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=10
2. http://www.aspheute.com/english/20000825.asp.
3. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/whoisclient.aspx

Comment: Ok I will try to make something like this. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

WHOIS is the protocol for querying domain information. So you probably want to implement this protocol.

As a starting point, you can use the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) about it.